# I get two different answers for the distance. Which one is right?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

This is very basic but i can't see why this is wrong.
$a =\frac{dv}{dt}$ $\rightarrow$ $adt = dv$. Integrating both sides yields $v= at$.
Inserting in $s=vt$ $\rightarrow$ $s=(at^2)$ which is wrong. I don't understand why it is wrong. I know if I take $v = at$ and multiply by $dt$ on both sides and integrate on both sides i get $s = \frac{(at^2)}{2}$ which is right. But why is the first answer wrong?

Comment: $s=vt$ only holds if $v$ is constant.

Comment: ohh.. Thanks,I knew it was something simple missing. Thanks!

Comment: Integrating you get $v=at+C$.

Comment: @CatalinZara I think I get it now. v= at + C, C is the initalvelocity. Now we can't use s = vt because the velocity is not constant (we assume a is not 0) --> v *dt = (at+C) *dt --integrating--> s =(at^2)/2 + C*t + C2 where C2 is the initial distance

Answer (score 0):

When $v$ is varying, we take mean velocity

$$ a = \dfrac {(v_{max}+v_{min})/2}{t} $$

If you mean $v_{max}= v , v_{min}= 0 $

then the factor $2$ explains itself.